# access angular route in nodejs app on heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

I am trying to host an angularjs project on **Heroku**. App works just fine on local and when running `heroku local web`.

But when trying to access, I am getting error `TypeError: response.sendFile is not a function`.

**Server.js**

```
 //Load HTTP module
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require("http");
var port = process.env.PORT|| 8000 ;
//Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Set the response HTTP header with HTTP status and Content type
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body "Hello World"
  response.end('Hello World\n');
  response.sendFile('views/main.html' , { root : __dirname});
  console.log(__dirname);
}).listen(port);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('views/main.html' , { root : __dirname});
});
console.log("\n\n\n"+__dirname+"Hello\n\n\n\n"); // prints /app in node 
console

console.log("\n\n"+process.version+"\n\n\n\n"); // v6.10.2

// Print URL for accessing server
console.log('Server running at '+port);
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "startup",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "bower": "1.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.10",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.12.0",
    "gulp-karma": "0.0.4",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-rev": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.7.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "lazypipe": "^0.2.4",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "wiredep": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
    "express": "^4.8.0",
    "gulp-bower-fix-css-path": "^0.1.1",
    "gzippo": "^0.2.0",
    "method-override": "~2.1.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp serve"
  },
  "description": "This project is generated with [yo angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) version 0.16.0.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "1.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Few points : 
 1. node version is "6.10.2"
    2.   express version is "^4.8.0"
    3.  res.sendFile with uppercase F or  res.sendfile with lowercase f, nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Instead of `http.createServer(function (request, response) {}` block, I added `app.listen(port);`

Answer (score 1):

What build pack are you using on heroku? Is it possible that you have an old version of express in heroku's npm cache? Try `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` and push a change to force a rebuild.

Also note that `sendFile` is present twice in your code so have you tried to replace it with `sendfile` at both places.